# Is it normal for an apartment complex to raise the rent on a long term tenant while listing identical vacant units at their original price?

Tags: united-states, rent, new-jersey

I have been at this apartment complex for 2 years now.

When I moved in two years ago, the rent for my unit was $2200/mo, which was reasonable for the market.

At the end of my first 12mo lease, the apartment manager tried to raise my rent to $2400/mo (~9% increase). I talked them down to $2300/mo, which is what I've been paying for the last year now.

My lease is due to expire in 2 months, so I got another notice saying they will renew my lease again, but at almost $2500/mo (~9% increase again).

However, what I don't get is that I can pull up their website, and see that there are units that are identical to my current unit, still listed at the original price of $2200/mo. Theoretically, I would save **$3600 over the lease period** if I just moved out and applied new for a different identical unit.

Is this normal?

Comment: Have you brought this up to your manager?

Comment: Not yet, i just received the notice today. But that was the crux of my argument during haggling last year, but I didn't really get an answer.

Comment: Some states  prohibit price rent gouging.  Laws vary.  Your situation might come under this umbrella.  I'd contact your state consumer protection bureau of equivalent to see if it does.

Comment: Wow, these rent prices are crazy to me.  I'm paying $925/mo for a 3-br house(in NC) and my rent only increases $25/mo annually(less than 3%).  Check your lease agreement and definitely check into what @BobBaerker said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, yes, this is common. The landlord thinks you are "locked in" and likely going to stay for a while, instead of move out. A modest increase in rent can be expected yearly, but only if they are increasing rent on everyone at the same time. As this comes during your renewal, it's suspect it isn't happening to everyone.

Reapplying for a different apartment isn't going to get you a reduced rate. Any normal landlord isn't going to approve you moving just to save rent money.

If you really are interested in moving, find a completely different landlord at a different apartment complex. That way they not only don't get the $300 increase for you being a multi-year tenant, but they lose your rent altogether and have to advertise for another apartment. This is a pain as well as kind of being petty, but I wouldn't blame you for doing it. I probably would.

If the increase was modest, like $50 and not happening a 2nd time in the same year, I probably wouldn't sweat it, since it'd cost more to move than the extra rent, but your situation sounds a bit shady.

As Bob Baerker mentioned, this may be considered price gouging and may be illegal in your area. Do a little research and maybe even contact a lawyer who specializes in tenant rights. They can give you the legal advice you need from there on.

Answer (score 2):

Is this through a medium or large corporate apartment complex?  Many of them have internal policy or contract terms that were put in when rents were going up 10% annually.  Some of them are just greedy, and like @computercarguy stated, the landlord/company figures that you will stay rather than move.

You could go in, demand to pay the $2200 current rate, or $2300, your rate, and see what happens.  Be prepared to move out, though.

I know/knew quite a few people who would apartment jump every year or two for reasons like this.  They would maintain a PO Box, and/or private mailbox service to keep the same "address" for work, bills, taxes, etc.

Good luck with the negotiations.

Comment: I would go one step further. Demand to pay $2000 because you're saving your landlord a lot of time and work trying to find a new tenant. Then agree on $2200. But yes obviously be prepared to move (But again, you're saving $3,600 for a year's rent just by moving (assuming rent is market based, which seems likely)).